# How to read Android .obb files?

Tags: android

I have developed a HTML5 app and my app size is increased to 80 MB but google play allows only 50 MB to upload. So i followed http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html and created an .obb file with package extension. But I am not able to read the file.